# Codeigniter controlling root directory even though it's setup in a separate directory

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I'm working on a codeigniter site which a friend helped me with previously. I'm learning the framework and codeigniter is setup in a subdirectory like:

```
 /var/www/example/codeigniteroothere
```

with the baseurl setup as that.

For some reason the codeigniter routes are effecting the root directory and other directories like:

```
/var/www/example/newfolder/index.html
```

which is getting routed through the codeigniter route and I can't pinpoint why.

I want to be able to upload static html files outside of the codeigniter folder and serve them up normally on my website.

Again, I'm just getting started so I do apologize in advance if this is a basic question.

I've looked into the routes, and I've checked my nginx server config file to make sure no weird redirects are being thrown. I can't pinpoint the issue.

The one weird route I found was:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)']
$route['404_override'] = 'over/over';
```

I tested editing the 404 override and that is certainly the one taking over.

But, my question is

1.) How is codeigniter controlling what's going on outside of the directory it belongs to? I understand that the ['(:any)/(:any)'] is taking over but how can it do that?

2.) What would you suggest to do to help fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .htaccess file inside your root folder with this configuration.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_env.c>
     SetEnv CI_ENV development
 </IfModule>
```